# Cucumber/Selenium: Stopping a false positive with a try catch block

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I'm using selenium and cucumber to automate a web application and I'm currently in a bit of a conundrum on cucumber sending false passes with how the API is built.  Basically I'm encapsulating a host of commands within a try catch block, and while it works fine, if a xpath were to change(unlikely) I would like to have the step essentially "fail" but not completely kill the program.  Here is where my code is:

```
@Then("^Create a meeting$")
public void meetingCreation() throws Throwable{
    try{
        //check to make sure driver is on calendar page

        ieBreakingThings = ieDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")));
        chromeBreakingThings = chromeDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")));

        if (!ieBreakingThings.isDisplayed() || !chromeBreakingThings.isDisplayed())
        {
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navigationLinkIcon icon-calendar']")).click();
            ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navigationLinkIcon icon-calendar']")).click();
            ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")).click();
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")).click();
        }
        else
        {   
            ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")).click();
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='CreateMeeting()'][@aria-label='Add Meeting']")).click();
        }
        //fill in text fields
        ieBreakingThings = ieDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")));
        chromeBreakingThings = chromeDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")));
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")).click();
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")).sendKeys("Web Release Test Meeting");
        ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")).click();
        ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'meetingName'][@ng-model='MeetingName']")).sendKeys("Web Release Test Meeting");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'MeetingLocation']")).click();
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'MeetingLocation']")).sendKeys("some address");
        ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'MeetingLocation']")).click();
        ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'MeetingLocation']")).sendKeys("some address");
    }catch(TimeoutException | ElementNotVisibleException ex){
        System.out.println("Meeting Creation Failed");
    }
    }
```

So the above works fine, but if an xpath were to change it would catch the exception, say the meeting creation failed, but cucumber would still report it as passing since it actually executed the method correctly.

Any advice?

Comment: You should also account for other possible exceptions, like NoSuchElementException or NullPointerException and a general catch-all, otherwise the exception will be ignored.

Comment: I don't think a NPE would ever happen in this block? But NoSuchElementException definitely.

Comment: After re-reading your post, you mention that it does detect an XPath change, but does not catch it as such in Cucumber.  Perhaps the ElelementNoVisibleException is working.  You may consider trying to place an Assert.assertFail(); in the catch block, which I would think would be detected by Cucumber.  I use JBehave which is similar, and does.

Comment: Assert.fail() does allow cucumber to recognize it as a failed step, but it also stops any further execution, which I do not want.  I would like cucumber to recognize it as a failure but to keep executing the rest of the program.

Comment: If you are using TestNG (we are using JUnit unfortunately, which does not support what I'm about to suggest) you can use a soft assert.  It is the equivalent of a verify command and will allow you to continue.  I do not recall the syntax.  Usually JUnit/TestNG does not come into question for those of us doing BDD like Cucumber/JBehave, but that would be my one reason to move to TestNG if you're not already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Cucumber will only report a failure if there is a failed assertion somewhere within the test execution. You could add in a (legitimate) assertion somewhere to verify something that you are expecting to see.

Comment: Correct, if I put in a failed assertion in the catch block to test that an exception is working it works, but stops all further execution.

Comment: I'm kind of looking for a "built in debug" for my code, so it'll say the method failed, but keep executing so I can quickly go to that method and see what the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to comment on your question itself but I would concur with Bill Hileman regarding using TestNG's SoftAssert: http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html

Comment: @TrevorScanlon You should look at ErrorCollector rule of junit4... As rules do not work in cucumber you will need to extend the ErrorCollector class. Override the verify() method, make it public and call the super class method with super.verify(). You can add errors with addError() method and finally call verify()...